# Active / Inactive icons in bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a sorting column with active / inactive sort on a column.My idea is to either gray-out the inactive columns or highlight the active column in a grid . I tried sth like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    Order By Status <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
</button>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JuCU6/)

I am not finding a way to highlight or gray-out icons for active/inactive state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `disabled` attribute to the button, and the font color will change to gray (including the font icon)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" disabled>
  Order By Status <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
</button>
```

If you don't want to actually disable the button, Bootstrap provides a "disabled" class:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm disabled">
  Order By Status <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
</button>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/JuCU6/2/

Comment: thanks @ssorallen, I found it by hit and trial.I think you mean by `class="btn btn-default btn-sm disabled"`

Comment: @sakhunzai Good point. I added an example with the "disabled" class as well.